# jboss7 heap size failed to allocate

Tags: jboss7.x

```
Exception in thread "management-client-thread 1-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: J
ava heap space (failed to allocate 536870928 bytes)
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:94)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.StreamUtils.copyStream(StreamUtils.java:49)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient$Rea
dAttachmentInputStreamRequestHandler.copyStream(AbstractModelControllerC
va:226)
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerCl
dAttachmentInputStreamRequestHandler$1.execute(AbstractModelControllerCl
a:202)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$2$1.doExecu
actMessageHandler.java:287)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, when I see things like this, my first inclination is to carefully comprehend the the stack trace.

Did you notice `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`?  It is a fairly good clue. Thankfully, it divulged exactly what the problem was:

> failed to allocate 536870928 bytes

The run-time system attempted to allocate a memory region whose size was 536870928 bytes .. ~0.5 GB.

If your application requires instantaneous creation of a single enormous object, or a collection of objects of enormous size, then you will likely need to alter the invocation of your Java program such that the heap can accommodate such an allocation.

Otherwise, if an allocation of this size is unexpected, I would examine where in your program a logical error may have been made for such an enormous region to have been demanded. One suspect might be an allocation of an array whose dimensions are not properly calculated or bounded.

Comment: Great Thanks.For this issue how much heap size we have to use? @ thanks in advance.

Comment: i mean JVM Heap Size

Comment: Well, this is rather awkward, as you are asking me, who knows nothing of your application's run-time working set memory requirements are, what an appropriate heap size ought to be. Seriously, please re-read my answer and at least make some effort to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what is the current heap size you have allocated? JVM defaults to 512M which is not much for real applications. Then examine your application what its doing to need more space.

Also the answer by David is slightly incorrect. Its not a single object needing the 0.5GB. When the JVM is running out of heap space it will ask the OS for memory to expand the heap using its own algorithm. When it can't get that much space from the OS, you get the error you are seeing. See this blog for more details. http://www.waratek.com/blog/introduction-to-real-world-jvm-memory-utilisation/

Comment: Yes, @Vijay, you are correct, the JVM's instantaneous demand upon the OS for additional heap space is is not necessarily due to construction of a single new object. But think about it for a moment: this suddenly enormous demand is not coming from promotion of new to tenured generation. It is most likely related to allocation of new object(s).

Comment: I'll edit my answer from "allocate an object" to "allocate a region".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it David, great answer.